# IE not rendering MVC4 DataType.Date EditorFor

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, internet-explorer

I´m making an MVC4 site, now I just created a View that has a HolidayDate Field. And it is not showing in IE and shows horribly in Chrome with lots of glyphs inside the textbox. I want to do it in IE like how the shows in chrome. But I don't want JQuery to do it.

Here is how I defined that property in my model

```
 [Required]
 [DataType(DataType.Date)]
 [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
 [DisplayName("Holiday Date")]
 public virtual DateTime HolidayDate { get; set; }
```

and in the View

```
 <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.HolidayDate) 
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.HolidayDate)            
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.HolidayDate)  
           </div>
</div>
```

And then how to get it to work on IE. Please anybody help

Comment: Create Editor Template view with the name `DateTime.cshtml`

Comment: Can you give some example code, Please.

Comment: I understand that you're speaking about date control in IE, it doesn't support html5 date control yet!.

Answer (score 0):

I see your Model property `HolidayDate` definition and decorations, they were good and it will generate  identical markup in all browsers but coming to date type, form input element it depends on the browser support for the html5 form elements. If browser doesn't support then it's behavior will fallback to text type input control.

For more cross-browser support info we can check at [CAN-i-USE feat=input-datetime](http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-datetime)

In order to see that behavior in non-supported browsers we should go with custom control(as you know one of the standard approach is displaying date control using [jQueryUI datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/))